# insert into many tables with the same button

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have to insert some input data ('date','resp') and update others(ng-repeat:'FraisFact','CodeEnvoiColis') with the same button, the probleme is that I m working with ng-repeat, and it inserts data many times: Im working with php and angularJS

```
$scope.updateAll = function(){ 
  var promises = $scope.selected.map(function(name) {
    return $http.post("http://localhost/deb/updatFact.php", { 
        'FraisFact':name.FraisFact,
        'CodeEnvoiColis':name.CodeEnvoiColis,
        'dater':$scope.dater,
        'resp':$scope.resp
      })
  });
  $q.all(promises).then(function() {
    console.log('All names are saved');
  });   
}
```

updateFact.php

```
<?php  

 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  

   if(count($data) > 0)  
 {   

      $DateFactureRecu = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->dater);  
      $RespFacture = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->resp);  

      $query = $query = "INSERT INTO facture (DateFacture,DateFactureRecu,RespFacture) VALUES (NOW(),'$DateFactureRecu','$RespFacture') " ;

      if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
      {  
           echo "Facture insérée avec succès..."; 

      }  

      else  ...
  }
   if(count($data) > 0)  
 {   

      $CodeEnvoiColis = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->CodeEnvoiColis);  
      $FraisFact = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->FraisFact);  

      $query = "UPDATE colis SET FraisFact='$FraisFact',NumFacture=LAST_INSERT_ID()  WHERE CodeEnvoiColis='$CodeEnvoiColis'" ;

      if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  ...

  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Show us the JSON and ask a question.

Comment: I don't have json, Imut the working with php and angularJS, I have to update many ng-repeat values in a table, and insert once value in other table. the update works but the insert no , I have the same insert many times

Comment: If you don't know that you are working with JSON or don't know how to get the JSON, then you have more problems than we can fix.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a beginner, that's what I understand from your question